# JavaServletHosting - Servlet Set Up

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, hosting

I've recently gotten some remote hosting for tomcat. My main directory has:

```
tomcat
--logs
--work
www
--WEB-INF
```

Aren't I supposed to have a conf and webapps directory? I tried copying the conf/webapps/etc directories directly from my local version of tomcat, but none of my servlets seem to be recognized by the server. I had placed the missing directories in the tomcat folder. The servlets I have put everywhere: in tomcat/webapps, in www, in www/webapps, etc.

Has anybody used javaservlethosting.com before? Do they have their own, specific configuration for tomcat? Could somebody give me a point-by-point guide to setting my servlets up? I'm a complete newbie to Java servlets.

Comment: I think you just got ONE single web application, not the entire tomcat hosting several web apps.

Comment: Which account type did you get?

Comment: @isnot2bad , you're probably right. If that's the case, should I move the content of tomcat's 'lib' to WEB-INF instead?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Tomcat SS I.

Comment: @user2392076 You have a Shared account. You should read their [KnowledgeBaswe](https://getnetportal.com/access/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=75) and use your [Customer Portal](https://getnetportal.com/access/).

Comment: @user2392076 yes, probably.